# how to solve tensorflow import problems?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed the tensorflow library but when I import the library it gives me the following error. Im̀ using python 3.9 and Fedora 35

`import tensorflow`

`The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.`
`Abortado (core' generado)`

I tried to install another version of the library but it interferes with other libraries.

Comment: TensorFlow haven't officially supported by fedora please follow this below article https://github.com/mrhhyu/tensorflow_fedora

Comment: TensorFlow is tested and supported on Ubuntu 16.04 or later, Windows 7 or later (with C++ redistributable), macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (no GPU support). For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install). Thanks!